# Sum binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\frac{k^2+k}{3^{k+2}} {n \choose k}}=?$$

What I've tried:

$$(k^2+k){n \choose k}=k(k+1){\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}$$
$$k^2+k = k^2-k+2k=k(k-1)+2k$$ =>

$$
\begin{align}
(k^2+k){n \choose k} &= k(k-1){\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}+2k{\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}}\\&={\frac{n!}{(k-2)!(n-k)!}}+2{\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}}\\&=n(n-1){n-2 \choose k-2}+2n{n-1 \choose k-1}
\end{align}
$$
and
$${\frac{1}{3^{k+2}}}={\frac{1}{9}}({\frac{1}{3}})^k$$

So I have

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} {\frac{n(n-1){n-2 \choose k-2}+2n{n-1 \choose k-1}}{9*3^k}}$$

And I'm stuck... Can anyone help me?

Comment: Hint: Your sum can be related to the second derivative of $\sum_{k=0}^{n}  {n \choose k} x^{k+1}$ which you can find a closed form for.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thank you! Fixed

Comment: @RagibZaman can you give me some hints where to read about dealing with binomial sums via second derivative?

Comment: @Mzia you have to be observative of the coefficients and practice manipulating these sums , there is no special thing to the second derivative, it can be the first of the forth and it depends on your sum and what coefficients are in it.

Comment: Mzia, in your last sum, ${n-2 \choose k-2}$ must be considered as equal to $0$ if $k<2$, and similarly for ${n-1 \choose k-1}$ if $k<1.$ (But may be this is what you  tacitely meant.)

Comment: The question is already solved, however I just want to mention that using creative telescoping algorithm, this type of sums are mechanically(algorithmically) computable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting where you stopped:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^n(k^2+k)\binom nkx^k&=n(n-1)x^2\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n-2}{k-2}x^{k-2}+2nx\sum_{k=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}x^{k-1}\\
&=n(n-1)x^2(1+x)^{n-2}+2nx(1+x)^{n-1}\\
&=nx(1+x)^{n-2}((n-1)x+2(1+x))\\
&=nx(1+x)^{n-2}((n+1)x+2)\end{align}$$
hence
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{k^2+k}{3^{k+2}}\binom nk
&=\frac{\frac n3(4/3)^{n-2}((n+1)/3+2)}9\\
&=\frac{4^{n-2}n(n+7)}{3^{n+1}}.\end{align}$$
However, as hinted by Ragib Zaman, there is a standard more direct way to obtain the generic formula above. Here it goes:

$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkx^k=(1+x)^n&\implies\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkkx^k=((1+x)^n)'x=nx(1+x)^{n-1}\\
&\implies\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nkk^2x^k=(nx(1+x)^{n-1})'x=nx(1+x)^{n-2}(nx+1),
\end{align}$$
and we recover the same result as above:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk(k^2+k)x^k&=nx(1+x)^{n-2}(1+x+nx+1)\\&=nx(1+x)^{n-2}((n+1)x+2).\end{align}$$

Comment: That's a cool trick

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed answer!

Answer (score 1):

As in the first hint
$$(\ x(1+x)^n\ )''= \left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n\choose k}x^{k+1}\right)''= \sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1){n\choose k}x^{k-1}= f(x)$$

So if you take $x= \frac{1}{3}$ :
$$\frac{1}{27}f(\frac{1}{3})= \frac{1}{3^3}\sum_{k=1}^n k(k+1){n\choose k}\frac{1}{3^{k-1}}= \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k(k+1)}{3^{k+2}}{n\choose k}= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{k(k+1)}{3^{k+2}}{n\choose k}- 0$$

And differentiate :
$$f(x)= (\ (1+x)^n+ nx(1+x)^{n-1}\ )'= 2n(1+x)^{n-1}+ n (n-1)x(1+x)^{n-2}$$

You can compute $f(\frac{1}{3})= 2n(1+\frac{1}{3})^{n-1}+ n (n-1)\frac{1}{3}(1+\frac{1}{3})^{n-2}= 2n(\frac{4}{3})^{n-1}+ n(n-1)\frac{1}{3}(\frac{4}{3})^{n-2}$

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please accept and upvote the answer if it helped.